# Facebook Login using Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, facebook-login

I'm using firebase for facebook login, but facing an error:

> An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error detail for
>   more information

When I click on the login button it will redirect me to facebook.com,
after providing email ID and password,

it will ask me for permission once I allow, I get an alert.

[image]

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns6Ks.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns6Ks.png)
You can Check your Authentication ......................... try

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this rules in Database rules

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": "auth != null",

      "users": {
        ".indexOn": "phoneNumber"
      }
  }   
}
```